# cannot access a simple bottle web page in Raspberry Pi from PC

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, html, raspbian, bottle

I followed the guide https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html
on Raspberry Pi with the following example

```
from bottle import route, run
@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81, debug=True)
```

Then I run the python script `sudo python hello.py`

The web page `http://<IP address>:81` is not available,
where `<IP address>` is the IP address of the raspberrry pi.

Running `sudo netstat --tcp --udp --listening --program`

I obtain

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name 
tcp   0      0     < IP address >:81        *:*                     LISTEN      26308/python`
```

Comment: `81 != 8080` Which portnumber would you like to use?

Comment: Thanks.You are right. The code above is wrong. The real code is 'port=81.I've updated the text

Comment: Why do you want that port? It requires sudo privileges

Comment: I tried also 8080. Behaviour is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iptable is blocking incoming traffic on port 81.

It works after the command
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong port.  (It looks like you may have copied the `bottle` "hello world" example without understanding what it's doing.)  To use port 81, make this change:

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81, debug=True)
```

Alternatively, just keep your code the way it is and access it at `http://<IP address>:8080/hello`

One reason to prefer port 8080 over 81 is that 81 requires root (sudo).